# How to install MySql UDF SYS (sys_exec and sys_val) on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: python, mysql, triggers, raspberry-pi, user-defined-functions

in order to execute python's program activated by MySql's trigger I understood UDF functions must be installed on Raspberry/Mysql environment.

I've already installed "default-libmysqlclient-dev" using Preference menu, Add/Remove software.

Wher mySql trigger runs i've receive this error: Errore SQL [1305] [42000]: FUNCTION SCHEMA01.sys_exec does not exist.

My understand is "default-libmysqlclient-dev" is not correctly installed in mySql application.

Can you suggest me a step-by-step guide (for dummies... like me) to download , install and configure UDF for Raspberry Pi4, please?

Thank you in advance.

Here some information may be useful to help me:

```
**pi@Rpi4:~ $ cat /etc/os-release**
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

**pi@Rpi4:~ $ uname -a**
Linux Rpi4 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

****pi@Rpi4:~ $ mysql --version**
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.39-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf
```

(armv7l) using readline 5.2

```
**MariaDB [(none)]> select @@version_compile_os, @@version_compile_machine;**
+------------------------+---------------------------+
| @@version_compile_os   | @@version_compile_machine |
+------------------------+---------------------------+
| debian-linux-gnueabihf | armv7l                    |
+------------------------+---------------------------+

**MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%compile%';**
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                  |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| version_compile_machine | armv7l                 |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnueabihf |
+-------------------------+------------------------+

**MariaDB [(none)]> select @@plugin_dir ;**
+------------------------------------------------+
| @@plugin_dir                                   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mariadb19/plugin/ |
+------------------------------------------------+

**MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'plugin%';**
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name   | Value                                          |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| plugin_dir      | /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mariadb19/plugin/ |
| plugin_maturity | gamma                                          |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

THE TRIGGER

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TESTTrigger01
AFTER UPDATE ON TableTrigger01 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = CONCAT('python /home/pi/Public/TEST_Email_v01.py');
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```